# Word vba conditional comdobox dropdown populated from excel

Tags: excel, vba, combobox, ms-word

The project is to reuse text previously written in reports where applicable for use in similar situations for future reports.  They will of course have to be edited in detail.

The immediate challenge is to use a conditional combobox in ms_word vba to get data from ms-excel, lookup in one column, return response in next column.

The code below comes from:shorturl.at/rwMW3  It crashes at the first Set statement.  Compile error: Syntax error.

This is the only code I have found for this application.

It crashes at the first Set statement.  Compile error: Syntax error.  Any help appreciated.   I have of course entered the actual full path and sheet name.

```
Sub FillCCLsitWithExcelData()
Dim xlapp As Object
Dim xlbook As Object    
Dim xlsheet As Object
Dim i As Long
Dim subject As String  
Dim bStart As Boolean
Dim ffield As FormField
Dim oCC As ContentControl
On Error Resume Next 
Set xlapp = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
If Err Then bStart = True
Set xlapp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
End If 
On Error GoTo 0
Set xlbook = xlapp.Workbooks.Open("D:\Data Stores\Data Source.xlsx")
        Set xlsheet = xlbook.Worksheets(1)
With xlsheet.Range("A1")
Set oCC = 
ActiveDocument.SelectContentControlsByTitle("Names").Item(1)
    For i = 2 To .CurrentRegion.Rows.Count
        Debug.Print .Offset(i - 1, 0)
        oCC.DropdownListEntries.Add Text:=.Offset(i - 1, 0), 
    Value:=.Offset(i - 1, 0)
Next i 
End With
xlbook.Close
If bStart = True Then xlapp.Quit
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Code comes from https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/populate-a-word-template-combo-box-with-excel-data/bed0bdb8-49fc-458a-9c1a-fd4b4d0649b2

Comment: There are two principle ways of populating a Dropdown or Combobox content control with Excel data, one using ADODB, the other by opening the file with Excel and reading the data that way. Both approaches are demonstrated at: http://www.msofficeforums.com/word-vba/42215-take-excel-list-add-word-combo-box.html

Comment: Tnx. Folloowing your link I come to: http://www.gmayor.com/Userform_ComboBox.html

Comment: Are you saying to crashes at the line `Set xlApp = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")`?